# run .msi file compiled from wxs without any installation whatsoever

Tags: wix, custom-action

How the wxs code below should be modified to make WiX 3.11 run custom actions only? (without any installation whatsoever)

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="RunNotepad" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="YourManufacturer" UpgradeCode="{E7A6D8C2-9F05-4A0F-B7C2-91A3B9D35F25}">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes"/>
        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes"/>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="RunNotepad"/>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="RunNotepad" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents"/>
        </Feature>
    </Product>
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER"/>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Component Id="RunNotepadComponent" Guid="{E7A6D8C2-9F05-4A0F-B7C2-91A3B9D35F25}">
                <File Source="tinytask.exe"/>
            </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="RunNotepad" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <CustomAction Id="RunNotepad" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" ExeCommand="[SourceDir]PL\PL.exe" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="asyncNoWait"/>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>`
```

as this is a non-standart use of .msi googling gives me no help (

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to achieve that functionality with VBScript run from [CURRENTDIRECTORY]. That is a property value of which is available before any installation begins